# how to set discord bot status

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I wanted my bot that have a status that says: my prefix is !.
codes i have tried:

```
client.user.setPresence({
   status: 'online',
   activity: {
      name: 'My prefix is "!" ',
   }
})
```

and the error was:
*cannot read property setPresence*.
so i tried

```
client.user.setActivity({
   status: 'online',
   activity: {
      name: 'My prefix is "!" ',
   }
})
```

and the error was:
*cannot read property setActivity*.
Please help me. my discord version:

```
^12.5.1
```

Comment: Can we see more of your code please? You might have `client` as `bot` in your code, or something along the lines of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
client.user.setActivity(`My prefix is "!"`, { type: "PLAYING" });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 client.on("ready", () => { 
        client.user.setStatus("online");
        client.user.setActivity('My prefix is "!" ', { type: "PLAYING"})
    })
```

[image]